# configuring github project with eclipse[EGIT]

Tags: eclipse, git, github, eclipse-neon

I have configured Eclipse with GIT plugin and also created a repository in github

now i want to add all my existing project from eclipse to the github repository through eclipse plugin

Can someone please suggest the steps

Answer (score 1):

I am able to checkin the projects, followed below steps

**creating git hub workspace**

1. open a git repository[window --> git repository]
2. click on clone a git repository
   in the uri share github clone url https://github.com/******/scala.git
3. select the local workspace director  in "Local destination" C:\software-Neon\Git-Workspace and click on finish

**adding project**

1. right click on project and then team --> share project
2. in the repository select the git repository created in step 2 and click on finish
3. right click on project and then team --> add to index
4. then right click on project and then team --> commit. enter commit messge then commit and push. [enter credential]

**retrieving existing project from github**

1. open Git repositories view
2. right click on Git-workspace then "pull" then finish
3. open package explorer  then import --> Git --> projects from Git
4. select  existing local repository -->workspace --> import existing eclipse projects
5. select the projects to be imported
   6.click on finish